# What does this mean in the Parallel Stack window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, task-parallel-library

I was trying to detect a deadlock a few hours ago.

When I paused the program I saw this info in the Parallel Tasks window

[image: Deadlock in the UI's thread]

I want to know why the first task doesn't show the "Location", "Task" nor "Thread Assignment"?

Is this the UI's thread (the main thread)?

Does this means that this is a task running on the UI's thread?

Comment: I'm not sure what this means, but I recommend looking at the Parallel Stacks window. It's _extremely_ clear about what's going on, though it's at the Thread level.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps task #1 is a [scheduled task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998369.aspx):

> Scheduled tasks do not have a value in this column.

Comment: Why doesn't it have the Status of Scheduled then?